# How can I clear query string parameter before executing a function on button click?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a button that simply filters through events based on the tags they have but I'm having a problem whereby the tag value in query string paramter does not clear when I click on other buttons. Instead the new filter tag value will stack with the one before making my filtered results inaccurate.

Here's a few code snippets.

To get the name of the tag and load with the filtered events on button press:

```
getCategory(category){
        if(category.value === 'All') {
            this.filterError = false;
        } else{
        this.selectedCategory = category;
        this.filterTags.push(this.selectedCategory);    
        }
        this.loadEvents();
    }
```

Buttons:

```
<div class="row categoryButton m-auto">
                <label class="mr-3 my-auto">Category:</label> 
                <button type="button" (click)="getCategory('Form 2')" class="col-md-2 btn btn-outline-secondary mx-auto mt-2">IGCSE</button> 
                <button type="button" (click)="getCategory('Form 3')" class="col-md-2 btn btn-outline-secondary mx-auto mt-2">Language</button> 
                <button type="button" (click)="getCategory('Form 4')" class="col-md-2 btn btn-outline-secondary mx-auto mt-2">Enrichment</button> 
                <button type="button" (click)="getCategory('Form 5')" class="col-md-2 btn btn-outline-secondary mx-auto mt-2">Art & Craft</button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to clear the array with each button click?

If so, add the following code *this.filterTags = [ ];* inside the button click event.

```
getCategory(category){ 

     this.filterTags = []; // Add this to clear the array
    
            if(category.value === 'All') {
                this.filterError = false;
            } else {
            this.selectedCategory = category;
            this.filterTags.push(this.selectedCategory);    
            }
            this.loadEvents();
        }
```

Comment: Sure. Thats what our community is for. To help each other. Could you please upvote my answer so that others could find it helpful. Thank you.